# Transform table per quantile

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a technical question for you plz.

I have this data form :

```
 Month <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    Typ <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
    nb_obs <- c(5,5,5,5,5,5)
    V1 <- c(369,    392,    352,    366,    352,    345)
    V2 <- c(525,    490,    473,    480,    475,    513)
    V3 <- c(680,    651,    664,    640,    621,    656)
    V4 <- c(727,    765,    690,    729,    753,    727)
    V5 <- c(580,    578,    553,    503,    542,    539)
    data <- cbind(Month, Typ, nb_obs, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)

 Month Typ nb_obs  V1  V2  V3  V4  V5
[1,]     1   1      5 369 525 680 727 580
[2,]     2   1      5 392 490 651 765 578
[3,]     3   1      5 352 473 664 690 553
[4,]     4   1      5 366 480 640 729 503
[5,]     5   1      5 352 475 621 753 542
[6,]     6   1      5 345 513 656 727 539
```

In my real data I have 1000 columns. I would like to transform this table so as to have the median as well as the quantiles of the "Vx" variables as new columns. Like :

```
Month <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Typ <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
nb_obs <- c(5,5,5,5,5,5)
median <- c(median(V1), median(V2), median(V3), median(V4), median(V5))
born_20 <- c(quantile(V1, probs = c(0.20)), quantile(V2, probs = c(0.20)), quantile(V3, probs = c(0.20)), quantile(V4, probs = c(0.20)),quantile(V5, probs = c(0.20)))
data_2 <- cbind(Month, Typ, nb_obs, median, born_20)

 Month Typ nb_obs median born_20%
[1,]     1   1      5  359.0     352
[2,]     2   1      5  485.0     475
[3,]     3   1      5  653.5     640
[4,]     4   1      5  728.0     727
[5,]     5   1      5  547.5     539
[6,]     6   1      5  359.0     352
```

I would like to have a column 0.40, 0.80; 0.30, 0.70; 0.20, 0.80; 0.05, 0.95. These are the intervals I will use to make `geom_ribbon` with `ggplot`. Can you get a solution with the `dplyr` package please ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to perform calculations column-wise. We could use `summarise_at` to summarise multiple columns and apply different functions.

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("V")), 
              list(new = ~median(.), q02 = ~quantile(., 0.2)))

#  V1_new V2_new V3_new V4_new V5_new V1_q02 V2_q02 V3_q02 V4_q02 V5_q02
#1    359    485  653.5    728  547.5    352    475    640    727    539
```

---

To restructure the data we can use `gather` and `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with("V")), 
            list(median = ~median(.), q02 = ~quantile(., 0.2))) %>%
    gather(key, value) %>%
    separate(key, c("col", "prop"), sep = "_") %>%
    spread(prop, value)

#  col median q02
#1  V1  359.0 352
#2  V2  485.0 475
#3  V3  653.5 640
#4  V4  728.0 727
#5  V5  547.5 539
```

You can add more `quantile` calls in the same `summarise_at` call if needed.

**data**

```
Month <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
Typ <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
nb_obs <- c(5,5,5,5,5,5)
V1 <- c(369,    392,    352,    366,    352,    345)
V2 <- c(525,    490,    473,    480,    475,    513)
V3 <- c(680,    651,    664,    640,    621,    656)
V4 <- c(727,    765,    690,    729,    753,    727)
V5 <- c(580,    578,    553,    503,    542,    539)
data <- data.frame(Month, Typ, nb_obs, V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)
```

Comment: Thx for your help. Is it possible to create new columns, like column "median" with all values of "V1_new, V2_new, etc." like my second table ? Thx !

Comment: @thomasleon in that case, use `mutate_at` instead of `summarise_at`, `data %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("V")), 
               list(new = ~median(.), q02 = ~quantile(., 0.2)))`

Comment: Thank you, but I may have been poorly expressed. Variables starting with "V" are observation simulations. My model gave me 1000 observation simulations in conditions "month" 1, "typ" 1, "nb_obs" 5. That is, a row represents the distribution of my simulations for a combination of month, typ, nb_obs. So creating a median variable by "contracting" the 1000 "V" variables makes sense here (the same thing for the quantiles "intervals" of the simulation). At the end I just want my columns "month", 'typ", "nb_obs" and "median" "q20" "q40" etc. Thx !

Comment: @thomasleon If you check your output you are calculating median values by column and attaching them to rows. Now you have 5 columns with `"V"` and 6 rows so when you are putting the value, the first value gets recycled. See how row 6 has got `359.0` and `352` which is same as 1st value. So if you want to calculate values columnwise you might not be able to attach it to your original data.

Comment: Thx for your answer. So, the `summarize_at` is good, but should recover the "Vx_new" and transpose them in 1 column "median" to have what I want, etc for the rest q20, q40 etc...

Comment: @thomasleon okay..updated the answer so that you now have all values in separate column.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `base R` by looping over the columns of interest with `sapply`, then apply the functions (`median`, `quantile`) on those columns

```
i1 <- startsWith(names(data), "V")
sapply(data[i1], function(x) c(Median = median(x), q02 = quantile(x, 0.2)))
#        V1  V2    V3  V4    V5
#Median  359 485 653.5 728 547.5
#q02.20% 352 475 640.0 727 539.0
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Month = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Typ = c(1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), nb_obs = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), V1 = c(369, 392, 352, 
366, 352, 345), V2 = c(525, 490, 473, 480, 475, 513), V3 = c(680, 
651, 664, 640, 621, 656), V4 = c(727, 765, 690, 729, 753, 727
), V5 = c(580, 578, 553, 503, 542, 539)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```